# yum localinstall and repo beginning with arobase (@)

Tags: centos, yum, repository

On a fresh CentOS 7 and for this example, I have installed epel-release using this command `yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm` instead of the usual one `yum install epel-release`

When I'm doing a `yum whatprovides /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo`, I've got this result:

```
# yum whatprovides /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: fr2.rpmfind.net
 * epel: mirror.hostnet.nl
 * extras: ftp.pasteur.fr
 * updates: ftp.pasteur.fr
epel-release-7-11.noarch : Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux repository configuration
Repo        : extras
Matched from:
Filename    : /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo



epel-release-7-13.noarch : Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux repository configuration
Repo        : epel
Matched from:
Filename    : /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo



epel-release-7-13.noarch : Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux repository configuration
Repo        : @/epel-release-latest-7.noarch
Matched from:
Filename    : /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo
```

Regarding the last listed package, what does `Repo        : @/epel-release-latest-7.noarch` mean and how to remove this weird repo from my system ?

NOTE: I've used the epel-release for this specific example. My real issue is exactly the same scenario but with a private repo & private package.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

It isn’t a repo per se, but it indicates that it is an installed package installed from an rpm file directly rather than from a repository.  I suspect if you run `yum reinstall epel-release` it will go away,  cause the installed file will be from the EPEL repository.